# Why the SQL view is not showing all the results from the UNION query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a view with 2 queries joined together with an UNION ALL. If I  run the query without the view it would display all the expected results but if I run the view would not display all the expected results. It's displaying the results of the first query running the view. Why does it happen?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TRAFFIC_ORDERS 
as
"First query"
  select date.id date_id1, date.date date, channel.channel_name, product.product_name, product.pay_type, orders.total, 
  orders.target, 
  0 as traffic, 
  0 as traffic_target /*Divided by 7 days to get a weekly target*/
  from orders
    inner join traffic on orders.date_id = traffic.date_id and orders.channel_id= traffic.channel_id
    inner join channel on channel.id = orders.channel_id
    inner join product on orders.product_id = product.id
    inner join date on date.id = orders.date_id
    left join traffic_target on traffic_target.week= date.week and 
    traffic_target.quarter= date.quarter and traffic_target.channel_id=orders.channel_id
UNION ALL
"Second query"
  select date.id date_id2, date.date date, channel.channel_name, product.product_name,product.pay_type, IFNULL(freesim.total,0) as orders, 0 as orders_target, uvs as traffic, IFNULL((traffic_target.target/7),0) as traffic_target
  from raw_coremetrics_page
    left join V_FREESIM_ORDERS as freesim on freesim.`date`= raw_coremetrics_page.date
    left join date on date.date=raw_coremetrics_page.date
    left join traffic_target on traffic_target.week= date.week and 
    traffic_target.quarter= date.quarter and traffic_target.channel_id=5
    inner join channel on channel.id = 5
    inner join product on product.id = 3
    where page like '%CHOOSER%' and category='CHOOSER'
```

Comment: Add sample data please.

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your interest but that would be difficult because is confidential data.

Comment: You mean you develop with confidential data?!? Scary...

Comment: The problem is that, at the moment we have *no* idea what data you're working with, *nor* what this view is currently returning, *nor* what the "correct results" you're expecting to see are. Try creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The results from the second query may be there, but at the end of the result set.  Alternatively, perhaps the view was created with only the first half of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Do with the following change:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TRAFFIC_ORDERS 
as
select * from (
  select date.id date_id1, date.date date, channel.channel_name, product.product_name, product.pay_type, orders.total, 
  orders.target, 
  0 as traffic, 
  0 as traffic_target /*Divided by 7 days to get a weekly target*/
  from orders
    inner join traffic on orders.date_id = traffic.date_id and orders.channel_id= traffic.channel_id
    inner join channel on channel.id = orders.channel_id
    inner join product on orders.product_id = product.id
    inner join date on date.id = orders.date_id
    left join traffic_target on traffic_target.week= date.week and 
    traffic_target.quarter= date.quarter and traffic_target.channel_id=orders.channel_id
UNION ALL
  select date.id date_id2, date.date date, channel.channel_name, product.product_name,product.pay_type, IFNULL(freesim.total,0) as orders, 0 as orders_target, uvs as traffic, IFNULL((traffic_target.target/7),0) as traffic_target
  from raw_coremetrics_page
    left join V_FREESIM_ORDERS as freesim on freesim.`date`= raw_coremetrics_page.date
    left join date on date.date=raw_coremetrics_page.date
    left join traffic_target on traffic_target.week= date.week and 
    traffic_target.quarter= date.quarter and traffic_target.channel_id=5
    inner join channel on channel.id = 5
    inner join product on product.id = 3
    where page like '%CHOOSER%' and category='CHOOSER')
```

Comment: Thanks Vinish but it's not possible because it says:  View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Create a view for each of your subqueries, then access those views from within your view V_TRAFFIC_ORDERS with union all clause.

Comment: Yeah! I did that and realize that the second query with a VIEW is not getting the results. Somehow one condition in the WHERE was the cause of that. I removed and then worked. No idea, but it works. Thanks Vinish